# Accessing multiple outputs of a Jar in a shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, sh

I am invoking a Jar(say abc.jar) which returns 3 outputs(which I have given as print statements in jar itself,say outputs from jar are

```
Emp name,Emp id and Email
```

and I was able to get these 3 outputs in the script in a single Variable which is not much of use.

I want to capture these outputs in 3 different variables to use them further.

Is there a way possible to store the different outputs of a jar into different variables in `.sh`?

```
details=$(java -jar /mydata/abc.jar)
echo $details
```

Output

```
Kevin 1234 abc@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you just need to evaluate the result and assign each value a variable.

```
$ details=$(java -jar /mydata/abc.jar)
$ r=`echo $details |gawk '{print "a="$1,"b="$2,"c="$3}'`
$ eval $r
# variable $a $b $c will store your value respectively
$ echo $a $b $c
Kevin 1234 abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: this line is throwing syntax error ( r=echo $details |gawk {print: command not found)

Comment: which command? replace `gawk` with `awk`? Are you in Linux/Bash shell environment?

Comment: I am running the script in Linux using command : sh scriptname.sh.

Comment: tried with 'awk' and 'pawk" as well still throwing same error.I think print command is the issue.I did not find any keyword named print w.r.t GAWK,PAWK or AWK....https://www.lifewire.com/linux-command-gawk-4094735

Comment: `print` has issue? it's ok in my environment. `$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.4`

Comment: `gawk --version GNU Awk 4.0.2`

Comment: Thanks @alijandro,it is working now.I was using single quotes instead of backtick..I changed them..its working now....thanks a lot for your help :)